# How to count number of views for a Post (Laravel Event Listener)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to count number of views for my products. For that there is a column `view_count`in my products table. I am trying to implement it with event listener.

This is my event code :

> ProductWasViewed.php

```
<?php namespace App\Events;
use App\Events\Event;
use App\Modules\Product\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ProductWasViewed 

{
    use SerializesModels;
    public $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

this is my listener code

> IncrementProductViewCount.php

```
<?php namespace App\Listeners;
use App\Events\ProductWasViewed;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Modules\Product\Models\Product;

class IncrementProductViewCount
{
    public function __construct()  { }

    public function handle(ProductWasViewed $event)
    {
        $event->product->increment('view_count');
    }
}
```

`EventServiceProvider.php` Array:

```
'App\Events\ProductWasViewed' => [
            'App\Listeners\IncrementProductViewCount',
        ],
```

Controller where i used the event listener:

```
public function singleProduct(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->name; 
    $product = DB::table('products')                    
            ->where('name' , '=', $name)    
            ->where('status','=',1)
            ->first();  
    Event::fire(new ProductWasViewed($product));

}
```

The error  that I am getting:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Events\ProductWasViewed::__construct() must be an instance of
>   App\Modules\Product\Models\Product, instance of stdClass given

How do i resolve the problem? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query Builder request returns `stdClass` object. You need to use Eloquent here to get `Product` object:

```
$product = Product::where('name', $name)->where('status', 1)->first();
```